# Can anyone please explain how getNamedQuery works

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

can anyone please help me to understand how getNamedQuery works?

```
    if(requestObj.getUpdateType().equalsIgnoreCase("U"))
        {
            if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
                logger.debug("Inside update");

            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("updateId");

            query.setParameter("id", requestObj.getId());
            query.setParameter("name", requestObj.getName());
            query.setParameter("createDate", requestObj.getCreateDate());

            int result=query.executeUpdate();

            if(result>=1){
                if(logger.isInfoEnabled())
                    logger.info("Data Updated for "requestObj.getId());
            }else{
                if(logger.isInfoEnabled())
                    logger.info("No data found for provided Id "+requestObj.getId()");
            }
    }
```

i have a csv file from which we need to read data and update/insert into database, first column of csv file is updatetype. if the update type is 'U' this means need to update data in database.
'requestObj' is object of my POJO class

what is "updateId" in Query query = session.getNamedQuery("updateId");?
what is id in "id", requestObj.getId() ? is it directly refer to database ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate, getNamedQuery(query) returns a JPA query defined in the XML configuration file. "updateId" is just the name of that query.

I do not know the type of requestObj, but I assume that getId() returns its unique identifier.

Comment: what is use of "updateId" ? and in (query.setParameter("id", requestObj.getId());) line what is significant of "id", can you please elaborate

Comment: I do not know the use of "updateId", since I don't the contents of the configuration file. I suppose by its name that it is a query which updates de object by its id. "id" means that you are setting the query parameter "id" with the id of the requestObj.